# Is there a way to export custom relationships (many to one and many to many) from SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, relation

I have a custom relationship (many to one) that I would like to export from one SugarCRM instance to another. All of the other module data has come across okay but the relationship data does not seem to be importable. Is there something I'm missing or will I just have to recreate my relations manually? Is it possible/advisable to go into the core db and try to extract this data?

Manual reproduction is do-able for this instance since it would only be about 60-80 relationships to recreate. In a larger instance though, I could see this being a dealbreaker (or a sort of lock-in).

Answer (score 1):

That is really tricky to support in the export/import process. I'd suggest just doing a direct transfer between databases or at least extracting straight from the database. There are also several ETL tools that exist that may be helpful such as Talend, but may be overkill for what you need.